# post query graphql with postman

Tags: java, graphql, postman

i'm trying to send graphql queries with postman, but seems it doesn't work.
I can't see what is the specific error, because i run this query in graphql and it works, but not in postman.
[image: this is the query in graphql]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it out like this,

```
query {
  report(id: "...") {
    name
  }
}
```